# Not receiving emails to local users after configuring Postfix with external domain

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I have configured Postfix running under Ubuntu server to only send emails, but since configuring with my external domain I am unable to receive (or send) emails to local accounts on the Ubuntu server .. e.g. root or myusername.As a result, I am not receiving any emails sent from internal systems such as cron or Smartd etc.

Running this command works :

```
echo "My message" | mail -s subject user@gmail.com
```

I am able to recieve the email on my gmail

However, this does not

```
echo "My message" | mail -s subject root
```

Looking at /var/log/mail, it appears to be appending my domainname to the send address..

```
Jan 29 11:48:46 media postfix/smtp[26029]: 6F3BEC0F80: to=<root@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=155925, delays=155925/0.04/0.06/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mydomain.com[EXTERNAL IP]:25: Connection refused)
```

In this example, I've replaced my actual domain with mydomain.com and EXTERNAL IP is my actual external IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/resolv.conf` 
and checked each of the ip addresses with 
`dig mx mydomain.com @IP_ADRESS_FROM_FILE`

One of them apparently has not yet been updated and contained an old DNS record, because of which the Postfix worked incorrectly.